# SQLite3 python doesn't work?

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-insert

I'm having a trouble with sql statements, when I try to insert data it seems to work, but when I check the table there is nothing there. I try to insert data using the below statement:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO song (title,artist) VALUES (\'{0}\',\'{1}\')".format(tit,art))
```

However when I do it through the terminal by the next way, it works:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO song (title,artist) VALUES ('Hide','Yellowcard')")
```

I tried also with %s to replace the string neither works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use SQL parameters; the `sqlite3` library uses `?` placeholders:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO song (title, artist) VALUES (?, ?)", (tit, art))
```

This has the added advantage that sqlite3 will figure out for you how to quote each value, prevent SQL injection attacks, and gives the database the chance to cache the query plan for the query and just slot in future values.

Make sure to commit your transaction.